# Django Advanced Filter not working in django-material admin Theme

Tags: python, django, material-design, django-advanced-filters

I am using django 1.9.5 and in admin panel i have imported django-advaced-filter and it works well but when i have changed my django admin theme to django-material then django-advanced-filter is not working i am only getting Title of django-material but the pop is not comming

Please see the above screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved by copying the files change_list.html (https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/master/material/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) 
in templates/admin/ 
and adding:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation ( );
```

at line 45